# JavaScript Adding Message Within The Following Else Statement

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys just wanted to find out how do I add a message to the existing alert code. EG: I just want to say thank you for your order and then display the form values all in one alert.

```
  else
{
    alert("name : "+name+"\ncakedonuts : "+cakedonuts+"\nglazeddonuts : "+glazeddonuts);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, I don't see an issues.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It would be helpful if you provided more context of the behavior you are expecting-- what do you mean "add a message"?  Do you want an additional `alert`?  Or just to add more text inside the existing alert?  Or something different?  Without sufficient context to meaningfully answer the question, you might not get much in the way of helpful answers.  Good luck!

Comment: What's the problem you want us to fix?

Comment: @ kfedorov91 @ JBDouble05 Yup the code is fine however I just want to add the message within the existing alert saying "Here Is Your Order" (something along those lines) I've tried adding a message like "Here Is Your Order"  within in the alert but cant seem to get it to display it only shows the form values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to say "Thanks for your order!" in one `alert`, then the order in the second `alert`, add an additional `alert`:

```
else {
    alert("Thanks for your order!\nname : "+name+"\ncakedonuts : "+cakedonuts+"\nglazeddonuts : "+glazeddonuts);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer however, not what I was after but that was my fault for the lack of context Im sorry. How would you do it so its only in one alert?

Comment: Changed! Any better?

Comment: Yup. Thank you so much! Ill make sure to describe my problem better next time sorry for any inconvenience, thank you for your time.